# Which software or API is best for extracting information from PDF and save to excel?

Tags: api, ocr, nlp

In my project there are lots of use of purchase order and sales order.
So, I have to enter data manually. So, is there any software and API of project that directly take PDF and give output in excel for example company name, date, amount, etc. Please share good sources.
thanks and regards.

Comment: Which language will you be coding in? I recommend Python - lots of good PDF libraries

Comment: I am free to choose any language. I just want to know which libraries can help me to solve this problem. Can you name any of them?

Comment: best choose a language which you know, although Python is very easy to learn, but also very powerful. @SteveBarnes is our resident Python guru.  Start by reading [this](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/)

Comment: I know python very well. Thanks a lot for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer expanded from comment, for future readers.

> is there any software and API of project that directly take PDF

You will find some good help [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/), which is chapter 13 of "Automating the boring stuff with Python", a great book.

It recommends using [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) , although it notes that

> PyPDF2 does not have a way to extract images, charts, or other media from PDF documents, but it can extract text and return it as a Python string.

That would appear to be enough for the OP.

As to the second part of the question:

> and give output in excel

well, the obvious is just to have your Python output CSV and to import that into Excel - which is what I would do.

Alternatively, [chapter 12](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) of the same book covers "Working with Excel Spreadsheets", and recommends [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) , which has great documentation, including a [tutorial](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).

Happy coding :-)